# Get Assets Storage Location in Dynamic Feature Module

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, dynamic-feature-module, dynamic-feature

I am working on [Dynamic Feature Module](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/dynamic-delivery), In which I am putting my `sqlte.zip` file under `feature->res->database->sqlte.zip`.

In my base app module, I want the database path of `sqlte.zip` as a String path after the zip is downloaded. The download is happening but I am not able to access that zip file?

Is there a way to access that file or Should I put the sqlte.zip in some other folder structure?

My current folder structure:

```
project
  |--app
  |--dynamicfeature
    |--src
      |--main
    |--res    (I have put my database inside this folder)
      |--databases
         |--sqlte.zip    <--- Here it is. I want to access this file inside my app base module.
```

Help Please!

Comment: Did you find anything on this ?

Comment: @duskandawn No. Nothing